# intermittent nginx timeouts having jetty as upstream server

Tags: nginx, jetty

We do have a weird production issue of `nginx` timeouts. The timeout says below :

```
"upstream timed out(110: Connection timed out)"
```

Here, the upstream server is `jetty` running on the same host where nginx is also running. Jetty is running on port `8080` where nginx is running on `443`.

Having checked the above error, I verified the logs of jetty logs and nginx logs. Though jetty is returning the response in less than a second, the response sent to nginx is being `delayed` by close to `60 secs`. And nginx is timing is firing the timedout alert after 60 secs with http response code of `504`. This is happening `intermittently`.

Below are the logs of jetty & nginx for a timed out request.

**Jetty log :**

> {"evt":1494519426927,"intelId":"50","intelSeq":112506,"intelVer":"1","time":"2017-05-11T16:17:06.927Z","uiCorrelationIdV1":"SUI-1494519425839-42047","threadName":"qtp754853679-357","wResource":"http://m.xxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/shoulder/_/N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roil","wMethod":"GET","wStatus":200,"wDurationMicros":1087801,"wJlpLocation":"","wFwdFor":"*NADA*","wHostHdr":"m.xxxx.com","wReferer":"https://m.xxxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/_/N-53f3Z7hk9?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style","wHttpVer":"HTTP/1.0","wWsgClientIp":"80.192.191.2","wSrcIP":"127.0.0.1","wUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0
>   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304
>   Safari/602.1","intelCropped":false,"intelLength":834}

**Nginx log :**

> 2017-05-11T17:18:09+01:00 intelId="56" intelVer="2" wMethod="GET"
>   wResource="/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/across-body/shoulder/*/N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roq4Z1z0roil?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style"
>   wStatus="504" wCacheStatus="MISS" wSrcIP="172.17.233.135" wSize="176"
>   wDurationSeconds="60.001" wHostHdr="m.xxx.com"
>   wReferer="https://m.xxxx.com/search/facet/women/womens-handbags-9780510203/shoulder/*/N-53f3Z7hk9Z1z0roil?search-term=Bags&sortBy=priceLow&facet=Handbag%20Style"
>   wSSL="on" wSSLver="771" wSSLciph="TLS1.2-ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
>   wWsgClientIp="80.192.191.2" wFwdFor="-" wJlpLocation="-"
>   wProtocol="HTTP/1.1" wUpstreamAddr="127.0.0.1:8080" wPort=443
>   s_vi="[CS]v1|2B4D4CA80501261B-600001064000B11D[CE]"
>   s_ppv="jl%253Asearch%2C14%2C100%2C5789%2C414%2C628%2C414%2C736%2C3%2CP" recognisedUser="true" wUiCorrelationIdV1="-" wUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0
>   (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1"
>   deviceType="mobile"

From the above two logs, we can infer that jetty returned a 200 response at `2017-05-11T16:17:06.927Z`, but it was received by nginx at `2017-05-11T17:18:09+01:00`. This 60 plus secs is causing the timeouts. Its bit weird as both nginx and jetty are hosted on the same host.

If someone could help us in debugging the issue or provide suggestions, it would be great.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your NGINX config? Is there any pattern to the failures? Do they happen at a particular time or type of request?

Comment: Thanks @FaisalMemon, have pasted `nginx.conf` here https://pastebin.com/K5NxKah0. These timeouts are happening at irregular intervals, no pattern is observed. And this is only happening for `GET` requests

Comment: Another observation, before timed out alerts, we are seeing below alert fired by nginx . `2017/05/11 06:41:51 [alert] 14485#14485: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 424b6374aeba3d9cc85ba5833e3163cd, count:1`

Comment: The above issue was discussed in https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_slowfs_cache/issues/4 and was said to be fixed in `1.10` version. Our current nginx version is `1.11`. Not sure why the above error is seen though we are on a higher version. Could this be the root cause?

Comment: Can you please post the config of the nginx `location` that handles the request?

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? Above request from Oliver will help further debug if so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `proxy_http_version` to make your [keepalive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) setting relevant. In addition, the `keepalive` setting should be in your upstream block.

e.g. add this to your config

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm little worried to apply these config changes as the issue is seen in production env. We saw  timeouts for `HTTP 1.0` requests version as well. Don't think `Connection` header also will fix as I'm seeing a combination of `Closed` as well as `keep-alive` in the timeout logs. 
I will apply this on one of our impacted non-prod environments and let you know.